# R Markdown pdf_document2 PDF figure and table numbers by section

Tags: latex, r-markdown, bookdown

I want to generate a `pdf_document2` PDF document in R Markdown where the tables and figures are labeled according to their section number. For instance, the first figure in Section 2 would be Figure 2.1. I can do that with `html_document2` but not with `pdf_document2`.

See below for the code that I have written. Right now the code generates continuous Figure numbers (Figures 1, 2, 3, 4) instead of Figures 1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2.

---

````
---
title: "Testing Section Numbers"
author: "Authors"
date: "January 2019"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    fig_caption: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: true
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 2
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
link-citations: yes
linkcolor: blue
subparagraph: yes
citecolor: blue
urlcolor: blue
---

# R Markdown

```{r pressure1, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="This is my plot"}
plot(pressure)
```

```{r pressure2, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="This is my plot"}
plot(pressure)
```

# Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure3, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="This is my plot"}
plot(pressure)
```

```{r pressure4, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="This is my plot"}
plot(pressure)
```
````

Answer (score 3):

The kludgey solution is to add some LaTeX commands to the header:

```
header-includes:
  \let\counterwithout\relax
  \let\counterwithin\relax
  \usepackage{chngcntr}
  \counterwithin{figure}{section}
```

Comment: Is there any update to how to do this with PDF output, that isn't "kludgey"?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `chngcntr` package, you can directly use `\counterwithin{figure}{section}` in your header includes (the command got included into the kernel in spring 2018):

````
---
title: "Testing Section Numbers"
author: "Authors"
date: "January 2019"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    fig_caption: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: true
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 2
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
link-citations: yes
linkcolor: blue
subparagraph: yes
citecolor: blue
urlcolor: blue
header-includes:
  - \counterwithin{figure}{section}
---

# R Markdown

```{r pressure1, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="This is my plot"}
plot(pressure)
```

```{r pressure2, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="This is my plot"}
plot(pressure)
```

# Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure3, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="This is my plot"}
plot(pressure)
```

```{r pressure4, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="This is my plot"}
plot(pressure)
```
````