# R Markdown pdf_document2 PDF bold greek letters

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr

I want to use bold Greek letters in R Markdown 
and modify a little example from 
[R Markdown pdf_document2 PDF figure and table numbers by section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863797), which reads as

```
---
title: "Testing Bold GreekLetters "
author: "Authors"
date: "January 2019"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    fig_caption: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: true
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 2
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
link-citations: yes
linkcolor: blue
subparagraph: yes
citecolor: blue
urlcolor: blue
header-includes:
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{bm}
---

# test bold greek letters

$\bm{\alpha}$ and $\bm{\beta}$

$$T^{2}=\left[\overline{\mathbf{X}}_{1}-\overline{\mathbf{X}}_{2}-\left(\boldsymbol{\mu}_{1}-\boldsymbol{\mu}_{2}\right)\right]^{\prime}\left[\left(\frac{1}{n_{1}}+\frac{1}{n_{2}}\right) \mathbf{S}_{\text {pooled }}\right]^{-1}\left[\overline{\mathbf{X}}_{1}-\overline{\mathbf{X}}_{2}-\left(\boldsymbol{\mu}_{1}-\boldsymbol{\mu}_{2}\right)\right]$$
```

Then errors occur as follows

```
! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again> 
                \mitalpha 
l.93 \(\bm{\alpha}
                \) and \(\bm{\beta}\)
```

How can I fix this problem? (PS: `\bm` in `\usepackage{bm}`; `\boldsymbol` in `\usepackage{amsmath}`)

Comment: my advice is to remove xelatex and just use `$\mathbf{\alpha}$`. This works fine for me.

Comment: @J_F Thanks! Yes, you're right! After removing `latex_engine: xelatex`, 
we can comment `\usepackage{amsmath}` and the `\usepackage{bm}` 
works well for both `\bm` and `\boldsymbol`, 
although `$\mathbf{\alpha}$` still does not work for me.
If we want to keep `latex_engine: xelatex`, what we should do?