# Bold italic capital Greek letters in maths

Tags: r, bookdown

I'm using R and Bookdown. In the *html* output I'd like to have an inline boldface italic capital Greek letter. I've tried a variety of inputs, for example

```
...some text $\bm{\varGamma}$ some text...
```

```
...some text $\boldsymbol{\varGamma}$ some text...
```

```
...some text $\mathbf{\varGamma}$ some text...
```

[This unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60693917/6090141) asks about boldface Greek, but the suggestion in the comments of using `\mathbf` works only with `\Gamma`. I haven't found any questions about italic capital Greek letters.

*Edit: the second input line above works, as explained in the accepted answer below. The real problem came from `\varGamma` which seems to cause trouble with [Bookdown's *epub* output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76304777/6090141).*

Comment: You could use the html entity `&#x1D71E;` but I guess you want to use it in math mode?

Comment: @GeorgeSavva yes I do. But thank you for the very useful tip, it's very handy outside of math mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boldsymbol` also works using `html_document`, but be aware of [difference between bm and boldsymbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/bm-package-versus-boldsymbol):

```
---
output: html_document
---

...some text **bold**: $\boldsymbol{\varGamma}$ some text... not bold: ${\varGamma}$.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** leaving this here in case it helps someone else although @Julian's answer is better in this case, poor mans bold is a last resort for bold fonts.

---

Try poor mans bold.  `$\pmb{\varGamma}$`

```
Regular math gamma:  $\Gamma$ 

Italic math gamma: $\varGamma$

Regular bold italic gamma doesn't work: $\mathbf{\varGamma}$

'Poor Mans Bold' Italic gamma does work: $\pmb{\varGamma}$
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'm noticing now that `\varGamma` itself is causing problems. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: What kind of problems?  Also, don't use my answer I think @Julian's is better.

Comment: The `\pmb` is a good backup solution in case bold versions are missing, thank you. The `\varGamma` gives "unexpected eof
  expecting "%", "\\label", "\\nonumber" or whitespace". I'm trying to understand the cause of this.

Comment: No idea.  Sounds like a new question but it might be something specific to your installation as it works for me (though I'm not using bookdown).

Comment: Thank you! I'll post a question on the Bookdown git site on this.

Comment: `\varGamma` was not recognized in the epub compilation. Disabling that solved the problem.